# Laravel task scheduler permission problem with cleanDirectory command

Tags: laravel-5, cron, schedule, laravel-artisan

I've set up a console command with a `handle()` function like this:

```
public function handle()
{
  $fileSystem = new Filesystem;
  $fileSystem->cleanDirectory('storage/app/public/tmp');
}
```

And in the console kernel I set up the command:

```
    $schedule->command('cleanupfiles:tmp')
              ->everyMinute()
              ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/taskoutput.log'));
```

The superuser's crontab has the following entry:

```
    * * * * * php /var/www/website/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I can see the task scheduler getting executed every minute by looking at the `/var/log/syslog`, so cron does it's job, but the folder contents are not cleaned. When I run the task directly on the terminal by: `php artisan schedule:run` I have the same effect; no files are deleted. Finally when I run the schedule with `sudo php artisan schedule:run` I see it works, files get deleted and output is written to `taskoutput.log`.

How can I solve this so the task runs with necessary permissions? Or is there anything else I miss here? Thanks.

Comment: You can try giving permissions to the user "www-data" or the user that you are using to the storage directory 


sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/project/storage

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others

Comment: the folder `tmp` is owned by www-data and it has write permissions to that folder. The upper folders such as `storage` on the other hand is owned by me  (not root) and www-data group and we both have write permissions. Do I need execute permission for www-data on `tmp` directory to delete files?

Comment: It doesn't give you some error when you execute the "php artisan schedule:run"?

Comment: Yes no errors there. Just says the command is due and executes it as everything is fine. And the log file `taskoutput.log` is empty.

Comment: @moonwalker Did you solve this problem?  I have exactly the same problem.